# Add font awesome icon to custom add to cart button in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, font-awesome

I changed the style of my Add To Cart with the help of LoicTheAztec,

but how to add a font awesome icon in front of button text using the followin code

```
// For Woocommerce version 3 and above only
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_link', 20, 3 );
function filter_loop_add_to_cart_link( $button, $product, $args = array() ) {
if( $product->is_in_stock() ) return $button;

// HERE set your button text (when product is not on stock)
$button_text = __('Not available', 'woocommerce');

// HERE set your button STYLING (when product is not on stock)
$color = "#777";      // Button text color
$background = "#aaa"; // Button background color


// Changing and disbling the button when products are not in stock
$style = 'color:'.$color.';background-color:'.$background.';cursor:not-allowed;';
return sprintf( '<a class="button disabled" style="%s">%s</a>', $style, $button_text );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, if font awesome icons are not enabled in Wordpress for your theme, you might need to add [Better Font Awesome](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-font-awesome/) plugin.

You can select any Icon code in this [fontawesome.com gallery of icons](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)

Now making a very small change to your code you will be able to add your desired Icon and size:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_link', 20, 3 );
function filter_loop_add_to_cart_link( $button, $product, $args = array() ) {
    if( $product->is_in_stock() ) return $button;

    // HERE set your button text (when product is not on stock)
    $button_text = __('Not available', 'woocommerce');

    // HERE set your button STYLING (when product is not on stock)
    $color = "#555";      // Button text color
    $background = "#aaa"; // Button background color

    // HERE set your fontawesome icon code and size
    $icon = 'fa-ban';
    $size = 'fa-lg'; // large - To disable size use an empty value like $size = '';

    // Changing and disbling the button when products are not in stock
    $style = 'color:'.$color.';background-color:'.$background.';cursor:not-allowed;';
    return sprintf( '<a class="button disabled" style="%s"><i class="fa %s %s"></i> %s</a>', $style, $icon, $size, $button_text );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

You will get something like:

[image]

> Font awesome possible sizes values:
>
> - smallest: **`fa-xs`**
> - smaller: **`fa-sm`**
> - larger: **`fa-lg`**
> - largest *(multiplicator)*: **`fa-2x`**, **`fa-3x`** … to **`fa-10x`**

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

**Add font awesome icon to custom add to cart button in Woocommerce 3
Copy Below Code and paste it to your theme functions.php**

```
/*STEP 1 - REMOVE ADD TO CART BUTTON ON PRODUCT ARCHIVE (SHOP) */

function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');

/*STEP 2 -ADD NEW BUTTON THAT LINKS TO PRODUCT PAGE FOR EACH PRODUCT */

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
global $product;
$link = $product->get_permalink();
echo do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton"><i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i></a>');
}
```

Comment: it's adding the icon but it is not removing the existing add to cart button. Any ideas, why?

Comment: Share Me Url so I will assist you, Maybe the version issue woocomerce