# Remove product button if out of stock from Woocommerce shop and archives

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

I am using [Add font awesome icon to custom add to cart button in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261566/add-font-awesome-icon-to-custom-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-3/50262262#50262262) answer code to remove the "add to cart" button from my products pages, but now whenever there is an article out of stock I get a "Not Available" label there which messes with the layout of my page.

I've tried disabling it, but with no luck, anyone knows how to hide the label?

Comment: This answer code doesn't remove add to cart button and has always work this way, disabling add to cart button and adding a custom label "Not Available" (with a custom icon)  as you can see in the code itself… If you want to remove the add to cart button, you need another code. So please your question explanations are just not right and you are making confusions.

Answer (score 2):

Use this snippet from the official woocommerce [documentation website](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/hide-loop-read-more-buttons-for-out-of-stock-items/).

```
if (!function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart')) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
        global $product;
        if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ) return;
        wc_get_template('loop/add-to-cart.php');
    }
}
```

Place this code into your **functions.php** file from your active theme or child-theme.

Answer (score 1):

To remove loop add to cart button when a product is out of stock use this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'out_of_stock_remove_loop_button', 2 );
function out_of_stock_remove_loop_button() {
    global $product;

    if( ! $product->is_in_stock() )
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.