# Remove read more button for out of stock item

Tags: php, css, wordpress, button, woocommerce

Ive been strugling with removing a "read more" or "beri dalje" button from my website. The website in question is [www.fotroviciliji.si](http://www.fotroviciliji.si) .

I can locate it and hide it in chrome investigator but not via global css or using php in functions.php.

The button has a class name btn border-grey product_type_simple. I tried to hide it via global css code. Display none does nothing, visibility hidden hides all the buttons including add to cart which I want to keep.

Then I tried to hide it with a php snippet from woocommerce: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/hide-loop-read-more-buttons-for-out-of-stock-items/ which actually hid all the correct buttons but messed up the add to cart function which then reloaded the whole page everytime I added something to cart. I added some unrelated code to functions.php.

I also tried this [Remove product button if out of stock from Woocommerce shop and archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500962/remove-product-button-if-out-of-stock-from-woocommerce-shop-and-archives) and it removes all the buttons including add to cart.

Please help Ive been at this for a couple of days and its driving me mad.

Comment: Right now im using this code for every product that is out of stock via global css :[data-product_id="16597"] {
display: none !important;
}. This works but is a temp solution since I have to add and delete once the item is back in stock.

Comment: I am not finding read more button in your given link can you give screenshots?

Comment: The button says "beri dalje". I'll put one back so you can see it.

Comment: See my below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add this CSS

.outofstock a.btn {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This CSS was only remove read more who is out of stock product.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful then, please accept and upvote.

Comment: I upvoted but my karma isnt high enough for it to be publicly seen.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I am new to this and I don't know which Woocommerce CSS file I should add this code to. Could you clarify that for me?

Comment: You can add this code in your active theme style.css file.